# LINQ IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, subsonic

I have a Menu class that has a IQueryable property called WebPages. In the following statement I am returning Menu items based on a match but I need to include the Webpages property. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
var allCategories = Menu.All().Where(x => x.CategoryID == 4 && x.Visible)
```

I need to extend it to check a property in the WebPage class, something like this..

```
var allCategories = Menu.All().Where(x => x.CategoryID == 4 && x.Visible && x.WebPages.Roles.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
```

That won't compile but I hope you get the jist of what I am trying to do.

NOTE: The Webpage property is filled by the PageID not CategoryID but not sure if that makes a difference??

Here are a brief outline of my classes.

```
public partial class Menu: IActiveRecord
    {
       public int ID {get; set;}
       public int CategoryID {get;set;}
       public bool Visible {get;set;}
       public int PageID {get;set;}
       public IQueryable<WebPage> WebPages
        {
            get
            {

                  var repo=NorthCadburyWebsite.Models.WebPage.GetRepo();
                  return from items in repo.GetAll()
                       where items.ID == _PageID
                       select items;
            }
        }
}

public partial class WebPage: IActiveRecord
    {
       public int ID {get;set;}
       public string Roles {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you mate.  You just need to say WebPages.Any, this will return true if any menus contain a webpage with your specified role.

```
var allCategories = menus.Where(menu => menu.CategoryID == 1 && menu.Visible && menu.WebPages.Any(webPage => webPage.Roles.Contains(roleToSearchFor)));
```

So the key bit that you need to add is this.

```
menu.WebPages.Any(webPage => webPage.Roles.Contains(roleToSearchFor))
```

Using the **Any()** function is very efficient as it will stop looking as soon as it finds a match.

If you used **Where()** and then **Count()** it would iterate through all the Webpages to find all matches and then iterate through the results to count them, so that would be much less efficient.

Below is a full source example for you to try.

```
    namespace DoctaJonez.TestingBrace
    {
        public partial class Menu //: IActiveRecord 
        { 
            public int ID { get; set; } 
            public int CategoryID { get; set; } 
            public bool Visible { get; set; } 
            public int PageID { get; set; } 
            public IQueryable<WebPage> WebPages { get; set; } 
        } 

        public partial class WebPage //: IActiveRecord 
        { public int ID { get; set; } public string Roles { get; set; } }

        public static class Launcher
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The Main entry point of the program.
            /// </summary>
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Menu myMenu1 = new Menu
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    PageID = 1,
                    Visible = true,
                    WebPages = new List<WebPage>()
                    {
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role1" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role2" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role3" },
                    }.AsQueryable()
                };

                Menu myMenu2 = new Menu
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    PageID = 1,
                    Visible = true,
                    WebPages = new List<WebPage>()
                    {
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role3" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role4" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role5" },
                    }.AsQueryable()
                };

                Menu myMenu3 = new Menu
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    PageID = 1,
                    Visible = true,
                    WebPages = new List<WebPage>()
                    {
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role5" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role6" },
                        new WebPage { ID = 1, Roles = "Role7" },
                    }.AsQueryable()
                };

                List<Menu> menus = new List<Menu>() { myMenu1, myMenu2, myMenu3 };

                string roleToSearchFor = "Role3";

                var allCategories = menus.Where(menu => menu.CategoryID == 1 && menu.Visible && menu.WebPages.Any(webPage => webPage.Roles.Contains(roleToSearchFor))).ToList();

                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want something like this:

```
var menuItems =
    from menuItem in Menu.All()
        where menuItem.Visible
            and (
                menuItem.WebPages.Contains(
                    webPage => webPage.Roles.Contains(
                        "role"
                    )
                )
                or menuItem.PageIsNull
            )
        select menuItem;
```

This should select only menu items joined to pages with the appropriate role.

Comment: I need those where the PageID is null also.

Comment: I edited the query above to include a check for null page. I don't know enough about your object model to know what syntax to use, but something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
public IQueryable<WebPage> WebPages
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<WebPage> WebPages
```

I think LINQ queries return IEnumerable...

Answer (score 0):

DoctorJonez thanks!!!

I'm putting this here as I have more space. I have 11 records in the Menu table, only 1 with a PageID set however if I use

```
var test = Menu.All().Where(x => x.WebPages.Any(pages => pages.Roles.Contains(Roles.GetRolesForUser()[0])
```

I get 11 records as the SQL run is this

```
SELECT [t0].[CategoryID], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedOn], [t0].[ID], [t0].[ImageID], [t0].[ImageIDHover], [t0].[Locale], [t0].[ModifiedBy], [t0].[ModifiedOn], [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[PageID], [t0].[ParentID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[URL], [t0].[Visible]
FROM [dbo].[Menu] AS t0
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM [dbo].[WebPage] AS t1
  WHERE ([t1].[Roles] LIKE '%' + 'User' + '%')
  )
```

If I run this I get the 1 record

```
var test = Menu.All().Where(x => x.WebPages.Any(pages => pages.Roles.Contains(Roles.GetRolesForUser()[0]) && pages.ID == x.PageID));
```

The SQL for this is

```
SELECT [t0].[CategoryID], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[CreatedOn], [t0].[ID], [t0].[ImageID], [t0].[ImageIDHover], [t0].[Locale], [t0].[ModifiedBy], [t0].[ModifiedOn], [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[PageID], [t0].[ParentID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[URL], [t0].[Visible]
FROM [dbo].[Menu] AS t0
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM [dbo].[WebPage] AS t1
  WHERE (([t1].[Roles] LIKE '%' + 'User' + '%') AND ([t1].[ID] = [t0].[PageID]))
  )
```

Is this a bug in Subsonic or am I not understanding it correctly?

The problem with Any() is that in the SQL as long as one record exits, doesn't matter which record it will return data.

I think effectively I am wanting an UNION SQL like below but I don't know how I re-engineer that into C#/Subsonic

```
select m.* from menu m where pageid is null

union

select m.* from menu m

join webpage p
on p.id = m.pageid

where p.roles like '%User%'
```

**I want to return all menu records and for those with a PageID set that the corresponding WebPage has the user's role in it.  If the user's role is not in the WebPage then I don't want to see it in my results.**

Comment: You could have edited your question to include this info since it seems to be further details on the question instead of an answer.